# R Quickly merge list of dataframes with datatable

Tags: r, merge

I have a datatable called `csv_t` with around 4.5m rows. I have a list of `data.frame`s called `binded2` which has 1,874 list elements. I'm trying to merge both by the column `index` in `binded2` and `tpl` in `csv_t`.

Because these datasets are so large, I am having trouble trying to merge `csv_t` with each `data.table` of `binded2` quickly.

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
func <- function(x,y){merge(x, y, by.x=names(x)[4], by.y=names(y)[1])}
binded3 <- lapply(binded2, func,csv_t)
```

What `binded2` and `csv_t` looks like

```
> binded2 # only first 3 elements shown
[[1]]
  start end     tpl   index
1     1   1 2222733 2222733
2     6   6 2222733 2222738
[[2]]
  start end     tpl   index
1     1   1 2222736 2222736
2     6   6 2222736 2222741
[[3]]
  start end     tpl   index
1     4   4 2222750 2222753

> head(csv_t)
    tpl strand base score ipdRatio
1: 3239      0    G     6    2.684
2: 3240      0    C     6    1.764
3: 3241      0    T     7    1.861
4: 3243      0    C    13    1.410
5: 3244      0    A     0    0.238
6: 3245      0    C     6    1.261
```

I would like to merge these two by matching up column `tpl` in `csv_t` and column `index` in `binded2`. I appreciate your help

[dropbox link to csv_t.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/evw2vbp100ye728/csv_t.csv?dl=0)

Comment: you could "collapse" binded2 using `do.call("rbind", binded2)` then the merge should be more straightforward (one call to `merge`)

Comment: so, `merge(csv_t, do.call("rbind", binded2))`

Comment: Do you have the development version, `data.table 1.9.5+`? This is a prime problem for using the new `on` argument.

Comment: @RichAtMango After collapsing and merging, how can I split up the dataframe back into its original separate dataframes?

Comment: gotcha - in that case, do this: `lapply(binded2, merge, y = csv_t)`.  which is pretty much what you had by the by.x and by.y lengths don't match

Comment: The canonical approach is probably closer to ``lapply(binded2,function(x)csv_t[x,`:=`(start=i.start,end=i.end),on=c(tpl="index")])``

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm not sure if I'm running your code correctly, I'm getting the error `Error: unexpected assignment in "lapply(binded2,function(x)csv_t[x,:="`

Comment: Yea, sorry, just noticed that my intermediate backticks got uncoded. try again. Before it read `:=` instead of ``. `:=` `` like it should

Comment: You may also want to wrap it in `invisible` so you don't get all sorts of unnecessary printouts.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still strangely getting an error:  Error in `[.data.table`(csv_t, x, `:=`(start = i.start, end = i.end),  : 
  unused argument (on = c(tpl = "index"))

Comment: The `on` argument is only available in the development version of `.data.table` (versions 1.9.5 and beyond); see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for instructions on installing this. Also, it's helpful to tag me (`@MichaelChirico`) so I'm sure to see you've responded.

Comment: Without using `on`, you can do: `setkey(csv_t,tpl); lapply(binded2,setkeyv,cols="index"); lapply(binded2,function(x)csv_t[x,`:=`(start=i.start,end=i.end)])` (the last two steps can be combined, if you prefer)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for the clarification. I'm using the data.table 1.9.4 version code without `on` however, i get that: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : x is not a data.table

Comment: You'll also need to do `lapply(binded2,setDT)` to convert the `data.frame`s to `data.table`s by reference. Note that in the development version, you can also combine: `lapply(binded2,setDT,key="index")`